# ¿Cómo calcular una fecha a partir del número de semana y día de la semana?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Desde el html tengo el nro de semana del año (de 1 a 54) y nro de día de la semana (0 a 6)

```
<label for="{{'domingo'+$index}}">{{ctrl.getFromWD(nroSemana.nrosemana,0) | date: "dd/MM"}}</label>
```

También tengo en el controller del js mediante una variable "year" el valor de cualquier año.

**Alguna ayuda para crear la función getFromWD() que calcule la fecha a partir de los datos (year, nroSemana, día de la semana) y lo guarde en una variable?**

Comment: Según recuerdo los días de la semana son 7, lo números del (0 al 7) hacen 8 días. Además debes definir cuál es el primer día de la semana y cuál es la primera semana del año.

Comment: si, ahi arregle. semanas (0 a 6) siendo 0 domingo. Suponiendo que el primer dia del año es sabado (6) y la primera semana del año siempre es 1

Comment: Magali, no me entendiste. Por ejemplo según la norma ISO, el primer día de la semana es Lunes (no domingo como los bestias de JS dicen), luego la primera semana del año es la que tiene más días del año, es decir es la semana donde se encuentra el primer Jueves. Pero esto no es así en todo el mundo, por eso pregunto. Y es importante, porque desde el primer día de la primera semana hay que empezar a contar para obtener el resultado que tú quieres.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A ver si entendi, yo aca paso un numero de dia (0 a 6), un numero de semana (de 1 a 53), y un año.

Con la semana y el dia calculo el numero de dias recorridos

Finalmente creo una nueva fecha con `new Date(y,0,totalDays)`

> (esto genera una fecha a partir del año indicado en el primer parametro `y`, el mes indicado en el segundo parametro, como le paso `0` lo omite y calcula el dia en base a la cantidad de dias recorridos en el año, que seria la variable `totalDays`. Docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date)

```js
function getFromWD(w,d,y) {
    var totalDays = ((w-1) * 7) + d + 1; 
    return new Date(y, 0, totalDays);
}

console.log("Primer dia del año: ", getFromWD(1,0,2023))
console.log("Ultimo dia del año: ", getFromWD(53,0,2023))
console.log("Ultimo dia del año: ", getFromWD(1,364,2023))
```

Te va a funcionar hasta 53 semanas, con 54 pasas al proximo año.
Y como veras, le puedo pasar numeros mucho mas grandes que solo de 0 a 6 para los dias. Deberias hacer tus propias verificaciones para que solo puedan llegar a la funcion los rangos de valores que vos querés.

Comment: Perfecto, muchas gracias!! si me sirvió :)